# Random input python generator

Tags: python, random, generator

I am trying to create a random question generator for helping me to revise. I have the problem of when i enter my answer correctly or incorrectly I will get an output of false twice in succession.

Here is my code, at the bottom I have commented lines.  They were for when I was only having the possibility of one answer, probably not needed but kept anyway.

```
import random
a = ('What is 1 + 2?')
b = ('What is 2 + 2?')

questions = [a, b]
answer = (int(input(random.choice(questions))))

answer = a
answer = b

if a == 3:
    print('Correct')
else:
    print ('False')

if b == 4:
    print('Correct')
else:
    print ('False')

#if answer == 2:
#    print ('Well Done')
#else:
#    print ('No Incorect')
```

Comment: What do you think the following lines are doing: `answer = a;
answer = b`

Comment: Your variables `a` and `b` are the questions, which are not equal to any number, so both `if` statements fall through to their `else`.

Comment: All `if` cases will be evaluated. If I entered `a==2` then `if a == 3:` is `False`, so `print ('False')` fires. But then it also will check against `if b == 4:` well... I guess that is `==('What is 2 + 2?')` in this case, so it is also `False` and you get `print ('False')` again.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Brain fart. Edited.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a bit.

```
import random
questions = ['What is 1 + 2?','What is 2 + 2?' ]
a,b = questions
x = random.choice(questions)
if x == a:
    l = int(input(a))
    if l == 3:
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('False')
elif x == b:
    l = int(input(b))
    if l == 4:
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('False')
```

If you don't understand what it does, just add print() statements :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to declare answer as a lambda function.

You might have better luck doing that:

```
...
answer = lambda q: int(input(q))
answer_a = answer(a)
answer_b = answer(b)

if (answer_a == 3):
....
```